# How to print page numbering while printing in Chrome based on table header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <button class="print">Print</button>

 <table id="a">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>aaaa</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel volutpat ante. Pellentesque maximus ipsum vel tempus scelerisque. Quisque vitae nunc est. Aliquam dictum magna nec quam aliquet accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim pellentesque
    lacus, vitae vehicula urna dignissim non. Phasellus eget odio efficitur, vehicula quam sit amet, dictum nisl. Vestibulum a sapien arcu. Nunc tristique, risus eu dignissim egestas, sem metus tincidunt odio, sed ullamcorper magna est eu sapien. Pellentesque
    volutpat vestibulum porttitor.
    </td>
  </tr>


</tbody>
</table>
  <button class="print">Print</button>

  <h3 class="pag pag1"></h3>
  <div class="insert"></div>
```

CSS:

```css
h3.pag {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  page-break-before: always;
  page-break-after: always;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

h3::before {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -15px;
}

@media print {
  h3.pag {
    display: initial;
  }
  .print {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
var bottom = 0; /* Position of first page number - 0 for bottom of first page */
var pagNum = 2; /* First sequence - Second number */
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* For each 10 paragraphs, this function: clones the h3 with a new page number */
  $("thead:nth-child(n)").each(function() {
    bottom -= 100;
    botString = bottom.toString();
    var $counter = $('h3.pag1').clone().removeClass('pag1');
    $counter.css("bottom", botString + "vh");
    numString = pagNum.toString();
    $counter.addClass("pag" + numString);
    ($counter).insertBefore('.insert');
    pagNum = parseInt(numString);
    pagNum++; /* Next number */
  });
  var pagTotal = $('.pag').length; 
  pagTotalString = pagTotal.toString();
  $("h3[class^=pag]").each(function() {
    /* Gets the numbers of each classes and pages */
    var numId = this.className.match(/\d+/)[0];
    document.styleSheets[0].addRule('h3.pag' + numId + '::before', 'content: "Page ' + numId + ' of ' + pagTotalString + '";');
  });
});
```

I am trying to include page number for every page while printing. I want the page number to be shown if there's a header for the following pages.

Currently, I can only based on `<tr>` to show the page number.
For example, if based on `<tr>`

```
$("tr:nth-child(9n)")
```

The page number will be increased every 9 rows.  I want to based on `<thead>` instead of `<tr>`. Whenever the `<thead>` appeared in another printing page, then I want it to be increased 1. How can I do that?